# Offline site and facebook scraping

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache, facebook, metadata

I have just created a new Joomla 3.3.6 website which has always been set to 'offline'. This is because my client doesn't want to launch until a specific date.

I have incorporated '*add this*' and '*share this*' buttons throughout the website. However when for example I click '*share this on Facebook*' the share link doesn't show my site meta info, but my hosting providers.

Eg it should display;

> "Music Website - join now for latest news and updates...etc etc"

Instead it displays;

> "Web hosting provider JustHost.com - domain hosting.. etc etc"

I have used the Facebook [URL Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) as this confirms the above. Seems to be scraping the incorrect info.

My question is how can I update this meta info, do I need to run the URL Linter as soon as I make my website live or is there some other way? I'm not sure how long I will have to wait for the facebook cache to clear.

I can't make the website live until the specified date. I'd rather not have visitors share the incorrect info. Has anybody else encountered this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#crawl and either what Nils suggested or an authentication plugin that gives offline access.

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/marco-s-google-tm-bot-access, an example of an plugin that does what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook (and most other portals) does need access to your site to harvest the data. There is no workaround and it's besides the common privacy issues a good thing as it prevents Facebook from flooding with spam content.

What you might can do:

1. Turn of offline-modus
2. Block access to your site via htaccess
3. Allow specific IPs to access your site (your IP, facebook IPs)